# How to make a grid fit its visible content?

Tags: css, overflow, css-grid

I have a grid representing a table (in red) with a header and body (in green):

[image: grid without body overflow]

My problem is that the table does not shrink when I give the body a height and clip its overflowing content:

[image: grid container]

How to solve that?

Here is the code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  border: red solid;
}

.header,
.body,
.row {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
}

.body {
  max-height: 35px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: green solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <title>Test</title>
  <body>
    <div class="table">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">Key</div>
          <div class="cell">Value</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">a</div>
          <div class="cell">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">b</div>
          <div class="cell">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">c</div>
          <div class="cell">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">d</div>
          <div class="cell">4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Subgrid's items are used to size the parent grid, even if the subgrid has some sort of `height` property set and the items overflow that height. With that in mind, the parent grid in your code will expand to fit all of the content in the subgrid, even with a `max-height` set on the subgrid.

Solution 1: Move the `max-height` to the `.table` and then position the `.header` sticky.

Solution 2: Change `grid-template-columns: subgrid` to `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto)`. This would allow you to keep the `max-height` on the `.body` like you have it now, but you'll lose subgrid.

From the [subgrid value spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#subgrid-listing):

> Rather than being specified explicitly, the sizes of the grid rows/columns will be taken from the parent grid's definition, and **the subgrid’s items will participate in the intrinsic size calculations of any tracks shared with the parent grid**. Essentially, subgrids provide the ability to pass grid parameters down through nested elements, and content-based sizing information back up to their parent grid.